# video.js videos are destroyed when container div hidden iPad

Tags: ipad, html5-video, video.js

The document has a number of divs only one of which is visible at any one time (others are display:none).

When a div which was visible is hidden and then made visible again the videos within the div don't play any more.

However this is only a problem on iPad.

Any suggestions as to how to re-initialise them?

thanks

Derek

Comment: It can be seen at: http://gordon/surveys/AKGW-YHSN/D3QY48N9/ - clicking on the Next/Previous buttons shows/hides the divs containing the videos.

Comment: sorry that link was faulty but the problem persists

Answer (score 3):

Having searched in every possible way for a solution it does seem that videos using video.js in a container that is hidden after video.js has initialised them become unplayable when made visible again.

So for now, when my pages detect that the browser is on iPad/iPhone they use the native video player.

To do this I place the includes for the video.js inside a javascript block in the head of the page so they are not loaded if iPad or iPhone is detected.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
if(!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) && !navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
    document.write('<link href=\"\/\/vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" \/\>');
    document.write('<script src=\"\/\/vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"\>\<\/script\>');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it shows really bad design for videojs tho, the main idea of videojs is to not have to deal with all these crap.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on firefox but it was because I was trying to stop the video after move its container div to a hidden div. I removed the "stop" code, the player seems to reinitalize?(and stop by itself) after being moved from one div to another on chrome, firefox and opera.

Before this simple solution, I thought to just re-add the video original html via javascript, it probably can be done after the div is hidden or before it is shown.